# Get Average of a column excluding the current month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like the average to be average excluding the current month counts.
I.e for November the average would calculated based on Jan-September values.

How do I do this using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Please update your question to include table definitions (DDL) and sample data in the form of `insert` statements.  Also specify expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a predicate to filter out the current month's rows.

```
where yourDataColumn <  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```